# Function doesn't match test results

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm supposed to run the file `assign2_partI_test_file` and get the results below. I just can't get the correct results.

My code:

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):

  result = ' '
  msg = 'List is: '
  for char in my_list:

      str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']

      if my_list == str_list1:

          result = msg + sep.join(my_list)

      return result
```

My output:

```
Start testing!

length Test

Start Testing!

length Test
List length: 7
List length: 0

to_string Test
List is: r, i, n, g, i, n, g
List is: r-i-n-g-i-n-g
None # (THIS IS SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY: List is: )
```

Test code:

```
import list_function

print("\nStart Testing!")

str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
str_list2 = ['r', 'e', 'd']
empty = []

print("\nlength Test")
print("List length:", list_function.length(str_list1))
print("List length:", list_function.length(empty))

print("\nto_string Test")
string = list_function.to_string(str_list1)
print(string)
string = list_function.to_string(str_list1, sep='-')
print(string)
print(list_function.to_string(empty))

print("\nEnd Testing!\n")
```

Comment: Your have been helpfully given test code, which clearly shows you the problem; your code doesn't do the right thing if the input is an empty list. So what have you tried to do to fix it? Note that your current code only `return`s anything inside the `for` loop; perhaps you should think more carefully on that.

Comment: Ok, I tried like more than 1/2 of the day. This was the closest , I can get to the intended output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this more as a review:

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):

  result = ' ' 
  # only needed because of the odd return
  msg = 'List is: ' 
  # fine, but you only use it once, so why not put the literal there?
  for char in my_list: 
  # why loop?

      str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g'] 
      # hard-coded the test...

      if my_list == str_list1: 
      # ...so you guarantee it only works for one input - why?!

          result = msg + sep.join(my_list) 
          # this line is useful

      return result 
      # but only inside the for loop?!
```

You can shorten the function to a single line (which you've pretty much written!), with the benefit that it would then make any sense at all and work.

---

Here is a simplified function that matches your function's output:

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    if my_list == ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']: # test case
        return 'List is: ' + sep.join(my_list)
    elif len(my_list) > 0: # any other non-empty list
        return ' '
    else: # empty list
        return None
```

Does that make things clearer? Should there really be such a big (or any) difference between those three cases?

Comment: Seriously, don't answer if you have no intention. seriously no thanks.

Comment: @Macrick what were you expecting? This isn't a code-writing service, and I've tried to highlight your mistakes. You've actually written the right code, then inexplicably surrounded it with a bunch of stuff that makes no logical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write other conditions in `elif` and `else` part ? You have written for one condition i.e. only when `my_list == str_list1`. But what happens for other conditions ? For example `empty` list ? You might want to check for that too.

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    result = ' '
    msg = 'List is: '
    str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
    if my_list == str_list1:
        result = msg + sep.join(my_list)
    elif my_list == []:            ## you can also use "len(my_list) == 0:"
        result = msg
    return result
```

Now the reason why you got had the issue `None # (THIS IS SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY: List is: )` was the `for` loop.`for char in my_list:` runs only when `my_list` is non-empty. But when you were passing the empty list then `for` loop wouldn't execute as it has nothing to iterate on.

Comment: Thanks, IÍI explore further down. Cheers

Comment: @Macrick Welcome. If you think my answer helped you then don't forget to upvote and accept it while leaving! :)